# Split an HTML table cell into two columns, table has no header

Tags: html

I saw some other examples on here on how to do this, but they all just used `colspan="2"` in the `<th>` HTML tag. In my case, I don't have any headers, so I'm trying to figure out how I'd still do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's a quick, small example of what I'm trying to do:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-modal">Name:</td>
      <td>Randon name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-modal">Project Name:</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-modal">Proj #:</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How would I be able to get the last cell `<td>12345</td>` to split into two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 choices so far.

## 1. You can add colspan=2 for every second TD except for it self, like following:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Name:</td>
            <td colspan=2>Randon name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Project Name:</td>
            <td colspan=2>XYZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Proj #:</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>67890</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## 2. You can embed another table inside of td like following (No need to put colspan=2 for every 2nd td)

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Name:</td>
            <td>Randon name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Project Name:</td>
            <td>XYZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Proj #:</td>
            <td>
                <table><tr><td>12345</td>
                <td>67890</td></tr></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colspan=2` in the second `<td>` elements of each row:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Name:</td>
            <td colspan=2>Randon name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Project Name:</td>
            <td colspan=2>XYZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-modal">Proj #:</td>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>67890</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very interesting. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!!